# Mongoose populate to a static array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

i have one schema and one array

this is my schema

```
const schema = new Schema({
    distributor_id: {
        type: String
    },
    user_id: {
        type: String
    },
    customer_id: {
        type: String
    },
    problem: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    note: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    created_by: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date
    },
    updated_by: {
        type: String
    },
}
```

and this is my array data

```
let problem_data = [{
            value: 1,
            label: 'error bill',
        },{
            value: 2,
            label: 'error system',
        },{
            value: 3,
            label: 'error connection',
        }]
```

my result data is like this:

```
"_id": "5fe86f3d6ff4936d7344d245",
"user_id": "5fa4f1c85d68ba373e2fb0b9",
"customer_id": "5f44e031cb22f81906cc1c6a",
"problem": 1,
```

the result i want is like this

```
"_id": "5fe86f3d6ff4936d7344d245",
"user_id": "5fa4f1c85d68ba373e2fb0b9",
"customer_id": "5f44e031cb22f81906cc1c6a",
"problem": {
     value: 1,
     label: 'error bill'
},
```

my question is is it possible to populate a mongoose schema based on an array?
if is possible how you guys solve this? or can i ask for some keywords?

Answer (score 1):

this is my tricky way to solve this problem
i do this because my frontend in cliet side ask me the data like the format i provided above

firstly i change my schema type to :

```
problem: {
     type: Object,
     required: true
},
```

then in my insert API i do this

```
let {problem} = req.body

 if(problem == `1`){
     problem  = { "value": 1, "label": "error bill" }
 }

 if(problem == `2`){
      problem  = { "value": 2, "label": "error system" }
 }

 if(problem == `3`){
       problem  = { "value": 3, "label": "error connection" }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do in your client side,

- This is your array data:

```
let problem_data = [
  { value: 1, label: 'error bill' },
  { value: 2, label: 'error system' },
  { value: 3, label: 'error connection' }
];
```

- make a object of your array data in `pData`:

```
let pData = {};
for (let p in problem_data) {
    pData[problem_data[p].value] = problem_data[p].label;
}
```

- query as per your requirement:

```
let result = await SchemaModel.find();
```

- just iterate loop of `result` from query and replace problem from `pData` object

```
result.forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.problem = {
      label: pData[doc.problem],
      value: doc.problem
    };
});
```

Comment: I think I agree with you, thank you for answering my question

the problem is my client side is asking for data like the format I provided above

i found a tricky way, I will describe it in the comments column